# Need a specific example of U-Matrix in Self Organizing Map

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to develop an application using SOM in analyzing data. However, after finishing training, I cannot find a way to visualize the result. I know that U-Matrix is one of the method but I cannot understand it properly. Hence, I'm asking for a specific and detail example how to construct U-Matrix.

I also read an answer at [U-matrix and self organizing maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174011/u-matrix-and-self-organizing-maps) but it only refers to 1 row map, how about 3x3 map? I know that for 3x3 map:

```
m(1) m(2) m(3)
m(4) m(5) m(6)
m(7) m(8) m(9)
```

a 5x5 matrix must me created:

```
u(1)   u(1,2)     u(2)   u(2,3)     u(3)
u(1,4) u(1,2,4,5) u(2,5) u(2,3,5,6) u(3,6)
u(4)   u(4,5)     u(5)   u(5,6)     u(6)
u(4,7) u(4,5,7,8) u(5,8) u(5,6,8,9) u(6,9)
u(7)   u(7,8)     u(8)   u(8,9)     u(9)
```

but I don't know how to calculate u-weight u(1,2,4,5), u(2,3,5,6), u(4,5,7,8) and u(5,6,8,9).

Finally, after constructing U-Matrix, is there any way to visualize it using color, e.g. heat map?

Thank you very much for your time.

Cheers

Comment: I think those are just euclidean distances from the first number. For example, u(2,3,4,6) means u(2,3) + u(2,4) + u(2,6), etc. But I am not sure, I am trying to ascertain this myself too. I came across your post googling around for an answer.

Comment: Did you ever get the solution?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if you are still interested in this but I found this link 
http://www.uni-marburg.de/fb12/datenbionik/pdf/pubs/1990/UltschSiemon90
which explains very speciffically how to calculate the U-matrix.
Hope it helps.

By the way, the site were I found the link has several resources referring to SOMs I leave it here in case anyone is interested:
http://www.ifs.tuwien.ac.at/dm/somtoolbox/visualisations.html

Comment: Providing some example code may enhance the understading of the `U-Matrix` concept.

Answer (score 1):

The essential idea of a Kohonen map is that the data points are mapped to a
***lattice***, which is often a 2D rectangular grid.

In the simplest implementations, the lattice is initialized by creating a 3D
array with these dimensions:

```
width * height * number_features
```

***This is the U-matrix***.

Width and height are chosen by the user; number_features is just the number
of features (columns or fields) in your data.

Intuitively this is just creating a 2D grid of dimensions w * h 
(e.g., if w = 10 and h = 10 then your lattice has 100 cells), then 
into each cell, placing a random 1D array (sometimes called "reference tuples")
whose size and values are constrained by your data.

The reference tuples are also referred to as *weights*.

*How is the U-matrix rendered?*

In my example below, the data is comprised of rgb tuples, so the reference tuples
have length of three and each of the three values must lie between 0 and 255).

It's with this 3D array ("lattice") that you begin the main iterative loop
The algorithm iteratively positions each data point so that it is closest to others similar to it.

If you plot it over time (iteration number) then you can visualize cluster
formation.

The plotting tool i use for this is the brilliant Python library, [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/),
which plots the lattice directly, just by passing it into the [imshow](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=imshow#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow) function.

Below are eight snapshots of the progress of a SOM algorithm, from initialization to 700 iterations. The newly initialized (iteration_count = 0) lattice is rendered in the top left panel; the result from the final iteration, in the bottom right panel.

Alternatively, you can use a lower-level imaging library (in Python, e.g., PIL) and transfer the reference tuples onto the 2D grid, one at a time:

```
for y in range(h):
    for x in range(w):
        img.putpixel( (x, y), (
            SOM.Umatrix[y, x, 0], 
            SOM.Umatrix[y, x, 1], 
            SOM.Umatrix[y, x, 2]) 
        )
```

Here *img* is an instance of PIL's *Image* class. Here the image is created by iterating over the grid one pixel at a time; for each pixel, *putpixel* is called on *img* three times, the three calls of course corresponding to the three values in an rgb tuple.

[image: Image1]  [image: Image2]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm afraid that it does not directly answer my question. I need to understand how U-Matrix works so that I can apply it into my application. Moreover, my application is developed in Java so I cannot use Python library :)

Comment: "It's with this 3D array ("lattice") that you begin the main iterative loop The algorithm iteratively positions each data point so that it is closest to others similar to it." Can you please expand on this? This is exactly what the question is asking. How, specifically, do you make this U-matrix?

Comment: doug: I'm afraid you have the u-matrix and codebook confused.  What you are plotting are the values in the codebook, i.e., an RGB representation of the vectors in the lattice.  The u-matrix is different, it represents the "distance" between neighbors in the lattice.

Answer (score 0):

From the matrix that you create:

```
u(1)     u(1,2)     u(2)   u(2,3)    u(3)
u(1,4) u(1,2,4,5) u(2,5) u(2,3,5,6) u(3,6)
u(4)     u(4,5)     u(5)   u(5,6)    u(6)
u(4,7) u(4,5,7,8) u(5,8) u(5,6,8,9) u(6,9)
u(7)   u(7,8)       u(8)   u(8,9)    u(9)
```

The elements with single numbers like u(1), u(2), ..., u(9) as just the elements with more than two numbers like u(1,2,4,5), u(2,3,5,6), ... , u(5,6,8,9) are calculated using something like the mean, median, min or max of the values in the neighborhood.

It's a nice idea calculate the elements with two numbers first, one possible code for that is:

```
 for i in range(self.h_u_matrix):
  for j in range(self.w_u_matrix):

    nb = (0,0)

    if not (i % 2) and (j % 2):
      nb = (0,1)

    elif (i % 2) and not (j % 2):
      nb = (1,0)

    self.u_matrix[(i,j)] = np.linalg.norm(
        self.weights[i //2, j //2] - self.weights[i //2 +nb[0], j // 2 + nb[1]],
        axis = 0
    )
```

In the code above the `self.h_u_matrix = self.weights.shape[0]*2 - 1` and `self.w_u_matrix = self.weights.shape[1]*2 - 1` are the dimensions of the U-Matrix. With that said, for calculate the others elements it's necessary obtain a list with they neighboors and apply a mean for example. The following code implements that's idea:

```
for i in range(self.h_u_matrix):
  for j in range(self.w_u_matrix):

    if not (i % 2) and not (j % 2):
       nodelist = []
       if i > 0:
           nodelist.append((i-1,j))
       if i < 4:
           nodelist.append((i+1, j))
       if j > 0:
           nodelist.append((i,j -1))
       if j < 4:
           nodelist.append((i,j+1))

       meanlist = [self.u_matrix[u_node] for u_node in nodelist]
       self.u_matrix[(i,j)] = np.mean(meanlist)
  
     elif (i % 2) and (j % 2):
       meanlist = [
                    (i - 1, j),
                    (i + 1, j),
                    (i, j - 1),
                    (i, j + 1)]
       self.u_matrix[(i,j)] = np.mean(meanlist)
```